# Formatting numbers in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a piechart using `ggplot2` library as follows:

```
ggplot(dat,
       aes(x = factor(""), fill = workers) ) +
       geom_bar() +
       coord_polar(theta = "y") +
       scale_x_discrete("")
```

The problem is that the numbers (`count`) are shown as `2e+05`. How can I show them as `20000`?

**Update:**

```
dat <- data.frame(workers=c("Q8","A2","S1","A2","A2","S1"))
```

Comment: You should post a reproducible example. The answer is probably along the lines of layering `scale_y_continuous` with some `label` argument while specifying what formatting the variable count should take, possibly by a call to `format`.

Comment: @shayaa: I added the reproducible example, but this example does not obviously show the issue with e+05, because I cannot post so many rows.

Comment: cant reproduce your formatting, even when replicating your data a million times to make the counts in the 1e6 range. Your problem might be `scipen`in `options`.

Comment: Are you using the `library(scales)` ?

Comment: @Enrique: yes, I tried to use it. But not sure if it's the best option to achieve the required result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `scales::comma` to handle this (and also easily make a reproducible example, even with a large amount of data):

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(
  workers = c(
    rep("Q8", 100000),
    rep("A2", 200000),
    rep("S1", 200000)
  )
)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(""), fill = workers) ) +
  geom_bar() +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_x_discrete(name="") +
  scale_y_continuous(label=scales::comma) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.border=element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())
```

which produces this monstrosity:

[image]

Note that you really should not display the "y" axis numbers since they make no sense in this context and should either direct label the pie slices or add the value #'s to the actual legend labels.

But, might I suggest turning to a different vis:

```
library(waffle)
library(dplyr)

count(dat, workers) %>% 
  mutate(trim=n/10000) -> df2

parts <- setNames(unlist(df2$trim), df2$workers)  

waffle(parts, rows=4, title="Count", xlab="Each square represents 10,000 workers")
```

[image]

If you're using the github version of ggplot2 you'll need to do:

```
waffle(parts, rows=4, title="Count", xlab="Each square represents 10,000 workers") +
  scale_fill_manual(name="workers",
                    values=c(Q8="#e41a1c", A2="#377eb8", S1="#4daf4a"), 
                    na.translate=FALSE)
```

as it has some different behaviour than the CRAN version (the `waffle` pkg will be updated when the new ggplot2 is on CRAN).

Comment: Thanks for the idea regarding the visualization. Just a small question: the command `waffle(parts, rows=4, title="Count", xlab="Each square represents 10,000 agents")` gives me an error
`Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 45 needed but only 8 provided.`, Though it's unrelated to this thread, but may you explain why do I have this error?

Comment: It seems that you have 45 levels (e.g., types of workers) in your data. The standard plot color palette is only of size 8, so ggplot runs out of colors. You need to supply more colors to the plot (e.g., via `+ scale_fill_manual()`).